# Многоуровневые списки / абсолютное позиционирование задержка с исчезанием

Tags: css, css3, position

Добрый день уважаемые. Подскажите пожалуйста как на CSS осуществить задержку в исчезание подуровней списка? Приведу пример

```css
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
}
li:hover{
  background-color: #0ff;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.firstLevl{
  width: 100%;
}
.firstLevl> li{
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  
}
.popUp:hover .secondlevl{
  display: block;
  transition: display 1s;
}

.secondlevl{
  display: none; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: -10px;
}
.secondlevl li{
   width: 150px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.popUp2:hover .thirdLevel{
  display: block;
}
.thirdLevel{
  display:none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 120%;
  top: 180%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="firstLevl">
  <li class="popUp">Первый уровень +++
    <ul class="secondlevl">
      <li class="popUp2">
        Второй уровень +++
          <ul class="thirdLevel">
            <li>Третий уровень</li>
            <li>Третий уровень</li>
            <li>Третий уровень</li>
            <li>Третий уровень</li>
            <li>Третий уровень</li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Второй уровень</li>
      <li>Второй уровень</li>
      <li>Второй уровень</li>
      <li>Второй уровень</li>
    </ul>
  
  </li>
  <li>Первый уровень</li>
  <li>Первый уровень</li>
  <li>Первый уровень</li>
  <li>Первый уровень</li>
</ul>
```

Задача как добраться до элементов 3-го подуровня, если списки спозиционированы таким образом? Я пробовал сделать задержку для перехода display:none -> display:block но у меня не вышло. Надеюсь что вы мне что-то толковое посоветуете?
Могу конечно, на JS запилить, но хотелось бы услышать вариант на CSS Если то возможно

Answer (score 3):

Не в ту сторону думаете. Вам нужна не задержка, а всего лишь поменять способ позиционирования вложенного блока.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  background-color: white;
}
li:hover {
  background-color: #0ff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.firstLevl {
  width: 100%;
}
.firstLevl> li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.popUp:hover .secondlevl {
  display: block;
  transition: display 1s;
}
.secondlevl {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: -10px;
  background-color: red;
}
.secondlevl li {
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.popUp2:hover .thirdLevel {
  display: block;
}
.thirdLevel {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  padding-top: 180%;
  padding-left: 20%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul class="firstLevl">
  <li class="popUp">Первый уровень +++
    <ul class="secondlevl">
      <li class="popUp2">
        Второй уровень +++
        <ul class="thirdLevel">
          <li>Третий уровень</li>
          <li>Третий уровень</li>
          <li>Третий уровень</li>
          <li>Третий уровень</li>
          <li>Третий уровень</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Второй уровень</li>
      <li>Второй уровень</li>
      <li>Второй уровень</li>
      <li>Второй уровень</li>
    </ul>

  </li>
  <li>Первый уровень</li>
  <li>Первый уровень</li>
  <li>Первый уровень</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Я не очень понял, зачем менять метод позиционирования.(Допустим по условию задачи под многоуровнивым списком находиться картинка, или слайдер, повер которого и должны отображаться элементы списка) Ваш метод хорош, только при условии что второй уровень хоть и находиться не в впритык к первому, но вертикально над ним. До третьего уровня вы так курсор не доведете увеличивая padding

Comment: @BlackStar1991 от чего же не доведу? просто нужно и у третьего уровня поменять способ позиционирования. Я полагал, что стоит мне показать пример, вы дальше сами разберетесь. Но раз не разобрались, отредактировал свой ответ. Цветом выделил области курсор над которыми позволяет видеть подменю.

Answer (score 1):

Замените `display` на `visibility` и установите разный `transition` для `.secondLevl` (задержка 2 секунды) и `.secndLevl:hover` (без задержки).

```css
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
}
li:hover{
  background-color: #0ff;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.firstLevl{
  width: 100%;
}
.firstLevl> li{
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  
}
.popUp:hover .secondlevl{
  visibility: visible;
  transition: visibility .2s;
}

.secondlevl{
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: -10px;
  transition: visibility .2s 2s;
}
.secondlevl li{
   width: 150px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.popUp2:hover .thirdLevel{
  display: block;
}
.thirdLevel{
  display:none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 120%;
  top: 180%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="firstLevl">
  <li class="popUp">Первый уровень +++
    <ul class="secondlevl">
      <li class="popUp2">
        Второй уровень +++
          <ul class="thirdLevel">
            <li>Третий уровень</li>
            <li>Третий уровень</li>
            <li>Третий уровень</li>
            <li>Третий уровень</li>
            <li>Третий уровень</li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Второй уровень</li>
      <li>Второй уровень</li>
      <li>Второй уровень</li>
      <li>Второй уровень</li>
    </ul>
  
  </li>
  <li>Первый уровень</li>
  <li>Первый уровень</li>
  <li>Первый уровень</li>
  <li>Первый уровень</li>
</ul>
```